# How to plot discrete time signal by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, signal-processing

Given the message signal `s(t) = 2cos(40*pi*t) - sin(12*pi*t)`, how to plot `s(t)` within 2 second, after 2 second, `s(t) = 0` with frequency = 200Hz and sampling number = 500 points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sampling a Signal at a Specific Frequency and for a Set Number of Samples

This question has several parts. The first task would be to create a vector `t` that has separated by the `Sampling_Period`. Here the `Sampling_Frequency` is equal to 200Hz, therefore the `Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;` which equals 0.005 seconds. This vector should run from 0.005 seconds (sample 1) to 2.5 seconds (sample 500). The second task would be to create a step function denoted as `u`. Here I use an anonymous function that is equal to 0 after time, t is greater than 2 seconds. By multiplying this step function with the sinusoid a truncated version of the function that is 0 after 2 seconds is created.

---

**Sampling Conventions:** 
Sampling Frequency = 200Hz
Sampling Period = 1/200Hz = 0.005s
Start Time = 0.005s
End Time = (Number of Samples) × (Sampling Period) = (500 samples) × (0.005s) = 2.5s

[image: Sampled Sinusoidal Signal]

```
%Sampling properties%
Sampling_Frequency = 200; 
Sampling_Period = 1/Sampling_Frequency;
Number_Of_Samples = 500;

%Creating the time vector%
Start_Time = 0;
End_Time = Number_Of_Samples*Sampling_Period;
t = (Sampling_Period: Sampling_Period: End_Time);

%Step function that ends at 2s%
u = @(t) (t <= 2);
s = @(t) (2*cos(40*pi*t) - sin(12*pi*t)).*u(t);

stem(t,s(t),'Marker','.');
title("Sinusoid Sampled at " + num2str(Sampling_Frequency) + " Hz and the First " + num2str(Number_Of_Samples) + " Samples");
xlabel("Time (s)"); ylabel("Amplitude");
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: your answer is awesome, but how can i upvote and accept your answer?